# How to implement two parameters that are each optional with available values for each parameter?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

Two parameters that allow user to choose either one to sort data.

```
SELECT comment, comment_type,user
FROM comments
WHERE (comments.comment_type = @ctype) OR (comments.user = @user)
```

The user must be able to select each commenttype or user from available values dropdown.  The problem is ssrs will not let me leave one blank.  I tried using IN but it errored out.

Comment: Will defaulting these to "NULL" not work?

Comment: What about allowing NULLs in the SSRS parameter?

Comment: I allowed NULLs but it is still prompting me to enter the parameter. I set both default values to NUll but it is still prompting me to enter parameter for each one.

Comment: It seems odd that you're prompted if you've allowed NULLs and set the default as such. Is this on your Report Server only? Even if you updated and deployed the report, the parameters are unaffected. It's an SSRS "feature". You'll need to update them on the server, too.

Comment: I think it is because there are available values for each parameter, and there is no null option?

Comment: Are you populating your parameters from a dataset?, if so, you could add a row with `NULL` as an option for your parameter

Comment: I did this and it seems like now the issues is it will not allow me to filter out BOTH.  So it is only filtering out one value at a time which is what I want, but I would also like it to filter out by BOTH if two values are entered.  I know I didn't include this in the question so I asked that in another one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
(comments.comment_type = @ctype AND comments.user IS NOT NULL) OR 
(comments.comment_type IS NOT NULL AND comments.user = @user)
```

Comment: There are available values for each parameter, and there is no null option maybe that is why?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO For me there should be `OR 1=1`

Answer (score 0):

You should check `Allow null value` in `Report parameters` window.

Than you can try your query or below query.

```
SELECT comment, comment_type,user
FROM comments
WHERE (comments.comment_type = coalesce(@ctype,comments.comment_type)) OR (comments.user = coalesce(@user,comments.user))
```

[**More information**](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/egiardina/archive/2007/06/26/sql-server-reporting-services-optional-parameters.aspx)

Comment: Because there are available values for each parameter it looks like I can't leave either one blank or null.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE PROC myproc (
@ctype varchar(10) = null,
@user varchar(10) = null
) as 
BEGIN

  SELECT comment, comment_type,user
  FROM comments
  WHERE (comments.comment_type = ISNULL(@ctype, comments.comment_type))
  OR (comments.user = ISNULL(@user,comments.user))

END
```